Activate conda via cmd file when conda is not on PATH
I need to be able to run a cmd file that then behaves like a anaconda prompt. Conda is installed in user profile without admin rights and hence is not on the PATH.
So what I did is copy the shortcut of the anaconda prompt and try with that:
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\mambaforge\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\mambaforge

running this in a open cmd window works and I can then activate the target environment. However when running this inside a .cmd file, it works but then execution stops and my environment is not activated.
The entire cmd file is:
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\mambaforge\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\mambaforge
conda activate myenv
do something

The activation never happens, command just stops but there is also no error message.
So how I can get conda to activate when executing a cmd file?

The solution is to use activate directly but with "call":
call C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\mambaforge\Scripts\activate.bat env_name

Without the "call", the cmd script stops after running activate.
